# How can I extend functionality of Embeded Terminal

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, build.gradle, intellij-plugin

I am writing a plugin for IntelliJ IDE to control the behaviour of "Embedded Terminal" through user given preferences. For this I assume my plugin would need to depend on `Embedded Terminal` plugin, So as described in this [post](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/plugin_structure/plugin_dependencies.html) I update following files of my plugin:

Updated `build.gradle` file with:

```
intellij {
  plugins 'org.jetbrains.plugins.terminal:0.1'
}
```

Updated `plugin.xml` with:

```
<depends>org.jetbrains.plugins.terminal</depends>
```

Now, when I run `runIde` task, I get following error:

> Cannot find org.jetbrains.plugins.terminal:0.1
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'recall-terminal'.
>
>   > Cannot find plugin org.jetbrains.plugins.terminal:0.1 at https://plugins.jetbrains.com
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 0s Cannot find plugin
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.terminal:0.1 at https://plugins.jetbrains.com

PS: Objective of my plugin is to open multiple tabs in different folders inside embedded terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of inbuilt plugins, only name of plugin is required in `build.gradle` file (not the full ID of plugin). Here's how my `build.gradle` file looks now:

```
intellij {
    plugins 'terminal'
}
```

`plugin.xml` still requires full ID of plugin:

```
<depends>org.jetbrains.plugins.terminal</depends>
```